# Twitter Bootstrap dropdown reuse in a tree

Tags: drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap

I have a tree and each tree item has a caret icon that will display a menu when clicked. I want to use Twitter Bootstrap style dropdown menus, however I don't want to include the menu markup for every tree node, as there can be a large number. I just want a single menu and I'll display the menu when the item is clicked.

Twitter Bootstrap menus do not offer this sort of functionality and are designed to be used in Nav Bars and buttons. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: if you can post some code or a test page screenshots , than we can definitely help efficiently

Answer (score 0):

I was able to hack this twitter bootstrap [context menu](https://github.com/sydcanem/bootstrap-contextmenu) code to do what I need.